# Which reagent Form 2 component function arguments are in use?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, reagent-forms

Which form is better?

```
(defn my-func [arg arg2]
 (fn [] [:div (str arg arg2)]))
```

Or this one?

```
(defn my-func []
 (fn [arg arg2] [:div (str arg arg2)]))
```

I'm writting from my phone so forgive me indentation...

Comment: Welcome! What do you mean by better?  Faster, more standard-correct, etc?

Answer (score 1):

There's other difference between these functions aside from arity.

The first function will close over `arg`, and `arg2` on first render, and use these arguments for each subsequent rerender. E.g.

```
(def a 1)
(def b 2)
[my-func a b]
```

will always result in `[:div '12']` whether or not `a` or `b` were changed

The second function will take `arg`, and `arg2` on each render and will update the result when arguments change.

Look for *Rookie mistake* in [reagent docs](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/CreatingReagentComponents.md#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question should be which one is correct(The first one is correct). The second one has got an **arity exception**. Based on your use case, I would prefer to define and call the anonymous function so as to get the results. Consider this number one edit:

```
(defn my-func [arg arg2]
  ((fn [] [:div (str arg arg2)])))
```